# unable to use openni2_launch

Tags: ros, asus-xtion-pro-live, openni2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

This is my first post on this forum!

I have been searching everywhere on the web and especially on this forum without finding any answer. Please forgive me if the answer was there and that I missed it!

I am trying to display an image from my xtion live connected on my beagle bone black to a rviz instance running on a virtual machine.

I am running ROS indigo on ubuntu 14.04 on both the virtual machine and the bbb. I followed the ros installation tutorials for ubuntu and ubuntu ARM.

- roscore is running on the virtual machine
- rviz is running on the virtual machine as well
- I set the ROS_MASTER_URI variable to the IP of the virtual machine on my bbb

When I run "roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch" on the bbb I get the following log :

Device "1d27/0601@1/3" with serial number "1208250036" connected

camera/driver-2 process has finished cleanly

The log file states :

Bond broken, exiting

I am able to open a depth stream using mjpeg_server and using "rosrun openni2_camera openni2_camera_node" but even though the IR sensor lights up I get no image either in rviz or on mjpeg_server

Can anyone help me ?

Full output of "roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch --screen" can be found here : http://pastebin.com/Q38VpuVq

Thanks

Regards,
Pouc

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192799/unable-to-use-openni2_launch/) by [pouc](https://answers.ros.org/users/20214/pouc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-09-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-16**:
It looks like the openni2 driver is crashing. Can you edit your question to include the full output from `roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch --screen` please?

**Comment by [pouc](https://answers.ros.org/users/20214/pouc/) on 2014-09-16**:
Hi ahendrix. Thanks for your answer. I have added the requested command output in the question as a pastebin link.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-17**:
I haven't seen anything like that before. It looks like some part of the nodelet infrastructure is crashing, but I'm not really sure how to go about troubleshooting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the answer to this question.

It was a communication problem between the openni2_camera node and the roscore node that is on a different machine

My bbb changed it's IP address because of a DHCP lease expiration

After updating the address in the hosts file this error is not occuring again.

Thanks ahendrix for helping me and I hope this thread will help others

---

Originally posted by [pouc](https://answers.ros.org/users/20214/pouc/) with karma: 16 on 2014-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0